# Change windows 11 taskbar color programmatically

Tags: windows, registry, dwm

I'd like to change the color of the taskbar in Windows 11, via a batch file, to blue (preferably to one that reminds you of the Age of Empires blue player, but any blue will actually do). Can use powershell commands invoked in said batch file, or completely done in a powershell script. Has to override any personalization, but can change the color of start menu and windows too, the important part is that it changes the taskbar color without external programs. It also has to account for it refreshing or not the taskbar color, if done through registry - this is the part where I gave up, since it sometimes did that and sometimes didn't for me. I'm a complete noob with powershell though, scraped together the code from Google and a registry logger. Here's my version, that works in theory, but sometimes doesn't update:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize' -Name EnableTransparency -Value $(0) -Force
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize' -Name ColorPrevalence -Value $(0x1) -Force
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name AutoColorization -Value $(0) -Force
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM' -Name ColorizationColor -Value $(0xc40078d7) -Force
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM' -Name ColorizationAfterglow -Value $(0xc40078d7) -Force
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM' -Name ColorizationGlassAttribute -Value $(0) -Force
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM' -Name AccentColor -Value $(0xffd77800) -Force
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent' -Name StartColorMenu -Value $(0xff9e5a00) -Force
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\History' -Name Autocolor -Value $(0xffd77800) -Force
pause
```

EDIT:
I've simplified the problem to just toggling between light or dark mode. It can be done in a number of ways, mainly by writing to the registry (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24038-change-default-app-windows-mode-light-dark-theme-windows-10-a.html) but Windows mode doesn't update automatically, only app mode. Also moved on to Windows 11. So can somebody tell me what can actually refresh the Windows colorization, mainly the taskbar, programmatically? Got a hint from a now deleted source that DWM might be the way to go, but again, how?

Comment: thanks. I didn't even know what to look for, so this much is super helpful :)

Comment: @Yoyó Can I know how have you solved it?

Comment: @ArnauMas nope :(